# Cannot use Powershell intellisense in Sublime Text 3 with LSP

Tags: powershell, sublimetext3, intellisense

my `LSP.sublime-settings` is below

```
// Settings in here override those in "LSP/LSP.sublime-settings",

{
        "powershell-ls":
    {
        "command":
        [
            "powershell.exe",
            "-NoLogo",
            "-NoProfile",
            "-NonInteractive",
            "-ExecutionPolicy",
            "Bypass",
            "-Command",
            "C:\\Users\\georg\\Downloads\\PowerShellEditorServices\\PowerShellEditorServices\\Start-EditorServices.ps1",
            "-LogPath",
            "C:\\Users\\georg\\Downloads\\PowerShellEditorServices\\pses-sublime.log",
            "-LogLevel",
            "Normal",
            "-SessionDetailsPath",
            "C:\\Users\\georg\\Downloads\\PowerShellEditorServices\\session.json",
            "-FeatureFlags",
            "@()",
            "-HostName",
            "'Sublime Text'",
            "-HostProfileId",
            "subl",
            "-HostVersion",
            "1.0.0",
            "-AdditionalModules",
            "@()",
            "-BundledModulesPath",
            "C:\\Users\\georg\\Downloads\\PowerShellEditorServices",
            "-Stdio"
        ],
        "enabled": true,
        "languageId": "powershell",
        "scopes":
        [
            "source.powershell"
        ],
        "syntaxes":
        [
            "Packages/PowerShell/Support/PowershellSyntax.tmLanguage"
        ]
    }

}
```

Root location of `PowerShellEditorServices`:
`C:\Users\georg\Downloads\`

When I click `LSP: Setup language server`, message below shows `LSP has no built-in configuration for a Powershellsyntax language server`

Using Powershell 5.1 on Windows 10 x64, with generated help files.
Link for Powershell config template for Sublime editor:
https://github.com/tomv564/LSP/blob/master/docs/index.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any language needs to be added under the `clients` heading, as per below:

```
{
    "auto_show_diagnostics_panel_level": 2,
    "clients":
    {
        "omnisharp": 
        {
        "command":
          [
            "/home/tb/prebuilt/omnisharp/OmniSharp.exe", // or eg. /usr/local/opt/omnisharp/run
            "-lsp"
          ],
          "enabled": true,
          "languageId": "csharp",
          "syntaxes": ["Packages/C#/C#.sublime-syntax"],
          "scopes":
          [
            "source.cs"
          ]
        }
    }
}
```